# Google Cloud Messaging, returning 401 Unauthorized

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, http-status-code-401

I followed the example on https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/notifications.html#gen-client trying to create notification key from client.

getAccounts() method did return a valid google account. GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(context, accountname, scope) also returns a valid scope string. 
However the response from the post on https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/googlenotification is 401, and is an html page:

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Unauthorized</TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
        <H1>Unauthorized</H1>
        <H2>Error 401</H2>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

By the way here is the request code I used to generate the notification Key on the client Side

```
request:
{
   "operation": "add",
   "notification_key_name": "appUser-Chris",
   "registration_ids": ["4"]
   "id_token": "id_token"
}
```

And concerning the Post Request I have used this URL

```
 https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/googlenotification
```

Along with this header information

```
content-type: "application/json"
Header : "project_id": <projectID>
```

PS : I also tried to include the Authorization Key to generate the notification key but it didn't work .

**Note : Keep in mind that I want to generate the Notif Key on the client side not on the server side.**

Wondering whether this is a known issue or anybody has any idea? Thanks!
And I would really Appreciate your help.

I have searched on forums as well as in stackoverflow , but I couldn't find any answer.

Comment: Are you using the 12-digit project number in the Developers Console for your `project_id` header?

Comment: yes I m using the project id (12 digit). and My GCM Service is enabled as well .

Comment: Can you double check your credentials? Make sure it is a Client ID (not an API key), and also of type "Web Application."

Comment: Client ID ?? where I should put my client ID ??

Comment: Yes client ID. Once you have it, place it in your scope like in the example: `final String scope = "audience:server:client_id:"
        + "1262xxx48712-9qs6n32447mcj9dirtnkyrejt82saa52.apps.googleusercontent.com";`. The string that ends in ".apps.googleusercontent.com" is the client ID.

Comment: Honestly I don't know what are you talking about . I don't need to use the client ID in my php Post Request . I have used the client ID to get the token ID , and it worked , but what I need right now is getting the notification key from gcm using PHP POST REQUEST.

Comment: I've got the same problem, have you found a solution?

Comment: @greywolf82 I think the error was from google server. because I tried it few days later and it did work without changing the code.

Comment: Looks like notification_key_name needs to be the email of the user that gets your id_token, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34298106/3983628).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) with local device groups on Android gives HTTP Error code 401](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34098773/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-with-local-device-groups-on-android-gives-http-erro)